# Khmer Unicode font not working in crystal Reports

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Khmer Unicode  font not working in crystal Reports showing the square boxes

but working in local after uploading to server not working.
using visual studio 2015 and Crystal Repor 13.

[image]

Comment: Has the font been installed on the server too?

Comment: yes installed in server

Comment: Long last one, solution I illustrated since 2008: https://osify.com/2008/12/khmer-unicode-with-crystal-report-in-c-application/#.Yfe0J_gxXSI but on different version.